# Python logger adapter log extra key work arguments

Tags: python, logging

I am wanting to create a custom logger class using the LoggerAdapter. What I want this class to do is to be able to update a context object (with keyword arguments), and then whenever a message is logged, pass in the dictionary of all the keyword arguments along with the message. For example:

```
logger = logging.getlogger(__name__)
logger.log('Some test message', extra={someKey='someValue'})
logger.log('Another test message')
```

And the output of that would be:

```
'{message: "Some test message", someKey: "someValue"}'
'{message: "Another test message", someKey: "someValue"}'
```

Is using the LoggerAdapter the right approach for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Seems so. Something like

```
logger = logging.getlogger(__name__)
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, {someKey='someValue'})
logger.log('Some test message')
logger.log('Another test message')
```

and you can change `logger.extra` at will including removing it with

```
logger.extra = None
```